# What are build team responsibilities from developer point of view?

Tags: continuous-integration, builds

Lets assume that you are working for a corporation doing a lot of IT development.

What do you think should be build team responsibilities that performs 'services' for developers?
What do you expect to be doing by yourselves and what tasks would you gladly pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would like fast build times.
2. I would like other devs build integrated fast if you have integrators. For example not two weeks integration time for different modules. I if a team has made a module it should be integrated fast.
3. If the build team are competent I would like them to understand the code and write the build scripts as a developer I hate this things. But most probably I wouldn't trust a build guy. For example we had a build guy how understood programing in one project so he made all the targets in the build files including compressing JavaScript and so on, this is a blessing but I think such a competent person is overqualified for build.
4. I expect them to have a nice homepage with statistics and downloadable builds.
5. I expect them to notify the developers who breaks the build. And like if they provided hints to why, especially if it's related to the build system.

**tl;dr** I want to type `git push` and have everything taken care for me. And some kind of "semi-atomatic" dependance update.

Comment: Personally I don't think that build team should create build scripts. Developers build their software anyway why duplicate the task in build team?

Comment: :) I understood that #3 was the controversial point. Many devs don't build locally. Just develop and check in to the build system on a dev branch and look if the build was green. On a second note there can be quite a difference between a dev build and a release build. For example I like my debugging to be made in many and small debug .js files. But a release build want one compressed large js file for faster network transfer.